# String allocation problem on each iteration

Tags: c++

l have a string like "hello_1_world". And in each iteration l want to increment "1" part. "hello_2_world", "hello_3_world" etc... So l can not use `const char*` or `string_view`. l have to allocate new memory in every iteration by using `std::string`. But, l do not want to because of performance issue. Could you suggest a solution?

So, my code is like below. Guess index is incrementing each time.

```
std::string value{"hello_" + std::to_string(index) + "_world"};
```

l tried so many ways. And one of them is like below:

```
string_view result(value, 39);
```

And concat something but again. l cant modify `string_view`

Comment: Have you tried: 1) Using `reserve()` to preallocate sufficient internal `std::string` memory, 2) Manually building the string, each, using the preallocated `std::string`, and 3) Using `std::to_chars` for the counter's stringification?

Comment: *But, l do not want to because of performance issue* -- So you are creating all of these strings, immediately after each other, in a loop?  If not, then I really don't see any issues if one string is created in one place, you do some code, and then the next string is created somewhere else, etc.

Comment: Put `std::string value;` outside the loop and inside do `value += "hello_"; value += std::to_string(index); ... value.clear();`.

Comment: ***l do not want to because of performance issue*** Is it really a performance problem that you profiled your code in a profiler? Are you calling this many times perhaps millions of times in your loop? What do you do with the strings anyways? Maybe how you use the strings afterwards is the performance issue?

Comment: I guess this is a theoretical question. If performance is really important, decide maximum index, then put enough leading zeroes so that it always fits without changing the length of the string. Then just replace the digit part of the string.

Comment: If leading zeroes are out of the question, then keep track of number of digits, and re-create string only when digit amount changes, otherwise just change the digits.

Comment: Finally, modern CPUs are really good at copying bytes, and modern compilers are really good at optimizing in surprising ways (including exploiting Undefined Behavior in unexpected ways, as a cautionary side note), so it may be that converting the index to a string is the slow part, and creating the string from 3 parts doesn't benefit from any optimizations.

Comment: But to my earlier comment -- do you actually have a tight loop, where you are creating these strings one right after the other?  If not, then I am sure that whatever code you have that occurs in-between the string creation virtually makes performance gains a non-factor.  Example:  `for (...) { create_my_string(); lots_of_more_unrelated_code(); create_my_string_again(); more_unrelated_code(); }` -- something like that, then the concern for speed, at least to me, is not significant.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a `std::string`, or will a simple `char[]` suffice?  If so, then try something like this:

```
// a 32bit positive int takes up 10 digits max...
const int MAX_DIGITS = 10;
char value[6 + MAX_DIGITS + 6 + 1];

for(int index = 0; index < ...; ++index) {
    std::snprintf(value, std::size(value), "hello_%d_world", index);
    // use value as needed...
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind having leading zeros in the number, then you can update just that portion of the buffer on each iteration:

```
const int MAX_DIGITS = ...; // whatever you need, up to 10 max
char value[6 + MAX_DIGITS + 6 + 1];

std::strcpy(value, "hello_");
std::strcpy(&value[6 + MAX_DIGITS], "_world");

for(int index = 0; index < ...; ++index) {
    std::snprintf(&value[6], MAX_DIGITS, "%0.*d", MAX_DIGITS, index);
    // use value as needed...
}
```

If you really need a `std::string`, then simply pre-allocate it before the iteration, and then fill in its existing memory during the iteration, similar to a `char[]`:

```
const int MAX_DIGITS = 10;

std::string value;
value.reserve(6 + MAX_DIGITS + 6); // allocate capacity

for(int index = 0; index < ...; ++index) {
    value.resize(value.capacity()); // preset size, no allocation when newsize <= capacity

    std::copy_n("hello_", 6, value.begin());

    auto ptr = std::to_chars(&value[6], &value[6 + MAX_DIGITS], index).ptr;
    /* or:
    auto numWritten = std::snprintf(&value[6], MAX_DIGITS, "%d", index);
    auto ptr = &value[6 + numWritten];
    */

    auto newEnd = std::copy_n("_world", 6, ptr);

    value.resize(newEnd - value.data()); // no allocation when shrinking size

    // use value as needed...
}
```

Alternatively, with leading zeros:

```
const int MAX_DIGITS = ...; // up to 10 max

std::string value(6 + MAX_DIGITS + 6, '\0');

std::copy_n("hello_", 6, value.begin());
std::copy_n("_world", 6, &value[6 + MAX_DIGITS]);

for(int index = 0; index < ...; ++index) {
    std::snprintf(&value[6], MAX_DIGITS, "%0.*d", MAX_DIGITS, index);
    // use value as needed...
}
```

Comment: This will rewrite the whole string, including "hello_", "_world" sequences.
He knows exactly where the number starts and ends. Why he couldn't replace directly in a char* only the area where the number is??

Comment: @StoicaMircea That will only work if the number of digits in `index` doesn't change, ie `0..9`, `10..99`, etc.  Whenever the number of digits changes, ie `9 to 10`, `99 to 100`, etc, then the offset of `_world` also changes.

Comment: Nope, starting position of "_world" will be always: strSize - 1 - 6.

Comment: @StoicaMircea That will place the `_world` at the very end of the string buffer regardless of what comes before it. In the OP's example, the `index` digits can be varible-length, so the starting position of `_world` depends on the ending position of the `index` digits. What you describe will only work if the number of digits used to hold the `index` value is fixed, using leading/trailing characters to fill in unused space.

Comment: You know all sizes, suffixSize, prefixSize and textSize. indexStartPos = 0+prefixSize; indexEndPos =  textSize - suffixSize. ALWAYS. Whats in betweend startPos and endPos should be replaced with the newest value of 'index' as string

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `std::stringstream` to construct the string incrementally:

```cpp
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "hello_";
ss << index;
ss << "_world";
std::string value = ss.str();
```

Comment: That will allocate a new `string` each time, which the OP doesn't want to do.

Comment: it works but stringstream is notoriously slow.